# is there a way to give different colors to tick labels in javafx?

Tags: css, javafx, colors

I have a bar chart and I can change default color value of tick labels by the the css:

```
.axis {
-fx-tick-label-fill: rgb(255,0,255);
}
```

However, it gives the same color to all labels in the chart as you guess.

I want to be able to give different colors to different labels. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: perharps you may want to add the `ID` of the chart instead of `class`?

Comment: how it will give different colors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the **ID** instead of the **class**.

You can add it directly in your FXML file with *fx:id* attribute or in your Java code with *yourLabel.setID(String id)*.

And then, in your CSS:

```
 #label1 {
    -fx-tick-label-fill: rgb(255,0,255);
 }

 #label2 {
    -fx-tick-label-fill: rgb(255,255,255);
 }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: let's say i want red color for the first label and blue for the eleventh label in my chart's category x axis. my question is about that.

Comment: i said diff colors for labels not axes.